# Updating values in cells excel

Tags: excel

Please find attached screenshot of my Excel doubt.

As in the screenshot, I want to update the 3rd and 4th row values in the 2nd row, leaving those dates without any value.

In the screenshot it is shown that in the question part 3rd row dates with `5/17/1997`  `5/18/1997` does not have any values. So want to leave those cell blank and update the rest with the date and values in the 3rd and 4th row, leaving those dates without value for the rest of the cells. Kindly help me with any functions or formulas for doing this.

[image]

Comment: Fill the first row of your solution part manually (e.g. dragging). For rows 2 and 3, use the formula combination of INDEX / MATCH. Wrap the index/match in an IFERROR clause, that returns "" if the error occurs. Let me know if these pointers are enough for you to work out your problem!

Answer (score 0):

First step: copy paste Row 3 to Row 10.

Formula in AUE11:

```
= IFERROR( If(Match(AUE$10, $AUE$4:$AUV$4, 0) > 0, AUE$10, "") , "")
```

Formula in AUE12:

```
= If(AUE$11 <> "", Index($AUE$5:$AUV$5, 1, Match(AUE$10, $AUE$4:$AUV$4, 0)), "")
```

Remember to format Row 10 and 11 as Dates, otherwise you might get numbers as a result (e.g. 35562 instead of 5/12/1997). Also, adjust the range (AUE:AUV) to your actual range.